# mutt: "Couldn't lock /home/{{user}}/Mail/sent"

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to get mutt working on ubuntu, but I keep getting the error:

```
"Couldn't lock /home/{{user}}/Mail/sent"
```

when i try to send mail. My permissions for `~/Mail` is `drwxrwx---`. I would really appreciate any advice on how to solve this.

I'm using bash for windows. Below you can see a excerpt of my `.muttrc` file.
I've left out stuff for security.

```
set folder = "imaps://exchange.ku.dk:993/"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed="+[ku]/Drafts"

set record="~/Mail/sent.lock"
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates

set move = no
set editor = 'vim'
set timeout = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that another service is blocking the file from being locked. Actually, you seem to be relaying your mails (as per your `folder` directive in your `.muttrc` file).

That will probably use `Postfix` underneath for the mail get relayed, and that's where I suppose the culprit is. Ubuntu systems come with a system to confine services to do only what they are allowed to do, and when you install `Postfix` it will automatically create a basic configuration for it (which doesn't include anything that you might do with `mutt`, of course).

To quickly test it, you might stop the `apparmor` tool by invoking:

- If you're using Ubuntu 14.04 or prior:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/apparmor teardown
  ```
- If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 or subsequent:

  ```
  systemctl stop apparmor
  ```

Then, try using `mutt` again. If it works, my assumption is right. In that case, you would need either to:

- Not define the `Postfix` configuration file in apparmor. For that, simply go to `/etc/apparmor.d`, find the postfix file under that tree and delete it, restart `apparmor` and you're done.
- Define `Postfix` configuration and extend it with your `mutt` additional configuration. For that, I recommend start learning [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/118328/how-to-create-apparmor-profiles-to-lock-down-programs-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 2):

First, check that there isn't another mutt process locking the file:

```
$ pgrep -a mutt
```

You can also check if there is another process locking the mailbox, just in case:

```
$ lsof /home/$USER/Mail/sent.lock
```

Otherwise, try deleting the lock file:

```
$ rm /home/$USER/Mail/sent.lock
```

Comment: Tried running these commands, and nothing come up. I however noticed that `Mail/sent.lock` has permission `-rw------`, even though `Mail` has permission `drwxrwx---`. Not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: Check the owner of the directory and the files. Also, make sure you have disk space. Posting your mutt configuration would help.

Comment: My user is the owner of both the directory and sent.lock. I've added my configuration to my post.

Comment: AFAIK the `record` value should be `"~/Mail/sent"`, without the `".lock"`.

Comment: Alright, I've changed that now. I have the same problem though. I now get a file called `Mail/sent`, and not `Mail/sent.lock`.

Comment: Clean any `send` or `send.lock` files. Try running mutt with `-d 5` and see if `~/.muttdebug0` gives any clue. Also, are you using Ubuntu or Windows? your question mentions both. Any special features of your filesystem, like being mounted remotely or an external drive?

Comment: filesystem is vanila. Windows 10 has a thing called "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows", which i'm using. Tried debugging and nothing new came up.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on FreeBSD and it turned out that I had set the sysctl security.bsd.hardlink_check_uid and security.bsd.hardlink_check_gid to 1. Setting both to zero got rid of that problem.